# PostGIS: Simple query selecting nodes of polygon

Tags: postgresql, geospatial, postgis

I know it's very simple but anyway: (Asked also at [gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158324/postgis-simple-query-selecting-nodes-of-polygon))

INPUT:

1. Regular OSM buildings .shp table
2. PostGIS Point location
3. RADIUS (around above location), lets say 500m.

RESULT:

I want to get back all corners from all buildings within this radius from location, that ("WHERE") they distance from location is less than DISTANCE (let's say 200m).

I'm struggling to get result as points accepting WHERE clause from polygons table.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, you need only the vertices within a radius, without the attribute of the polygons? If yes, you can do it with a subquery, which first extracts all vertices, and than query the result of the subquery with ST_DWithin:

```
WITH vertices AS (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom FROM buildings)
    SELECT geom from vertices 
    WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5 45)',4326), 100);
```

For a better performance you can also add the same WHERE condition within the subquery:

```
WITH vertices AS (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom FROM buildings
                    WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5 45)',4326), 100)
                  )
    SELECT geom from vertices 
    WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5 45)',4326), 100);
```

Comment: I don't completely understand why in the version with improved performance we need the second where? It seems that the first where will do all the job, and therefore, maybe we don't need the outer query at all? Or am I missing some basic SQL? Thanks,

Comment: 1) Yes, the first version do the job, but the second one could be faster, specially if you have big amount of data. With the where condition in the subquery, it will not query polygons, which are anyway not relevant for the main query. 2) You need the outer query because you need only the vertices within the radius, and not all vertices of the polygons within the radius (I hope, I interpreted your question correctly)

Comment: @Tommasco Di Bucchianico The second condition is that the line between each vertex and the point is not intersected by any other building around. Thanks,

Comment: In order to check intersections, you must first build lines. This is a complex topic, please ask another question.

Comment: @Tommasco Di Bucchianico thanks, please see at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018767/postgis-selecting-nodes-of-polygon-without-intersection